# Whenever a cell in QTableView is selected, an unrelated QPushButton gains focus along with the cell

Tags: qt

I have a `QTabWidget`, that on a particular tab holds a `QTableView` subclass and a `QHBoxLayout` of `QPushButtons` (Insert, Delete, Fill/Calc, Copy, Paste).

[image]

The red circles show that whenever I make a selection in the `QTableView`, the `Insert` button also gains selection.

[image]

As a result, when the user types into the Segment Name line edit and hits enter (to submit the changes), the changes are submitted *and the insert button is activated*.

What can I do to make the `QTableView` cells and the `Insert` button mutually exclusive for selection?

In other words, when a user clicks on a table cell I do not want any buttons selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your button is `default`.

Change it to false.

```
ui->insertButton->setDefault(false);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#default-prop

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop